# Xpath: find data not contained in tags

Tags: xpath, xquery

I'm trying to target data that is not located unside a tag (other than the all encompassing p)

```
<p>
    <strong>id1:</strong>data1<br />
    data2<br />
    <strong>id3:</strong>data3<br />
    <strong>id4:</strong>data4
</p>
<p>
    <strong>id1:</strong>data1<br />
    data2<br />
    <strong>id3:</strong>data3
</p>
```

Any suggestions how I can get data1, data2, and data3 and be able to identify them uniquely (for example data3 follows the `strong[.='id3:']` and ends before the `<br/>`)

**EDIT:** data2 always follows data1 after a `<br/>`
Thanks

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for explanation and several alternative solutions. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find the text node that immediately follows `<strong>id1</strong>`, use `strong[.='id1']/following-sibling::text()[1]` (with the p element as your context node).

This assumes that you know there will be such a text node. A more rigorous test is `strong[.='id1']/following-sibling::node()[1][self::text()]` which will find the first node (of any kind) after the strong element, and return it provided that it turns out to be a text node.

It's not clear how you want to identify data2 in your example.

Comment: data2 always follows data1 after a `<br/>`, but thanks this was what I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

**Just use**:

```
p/text()
```

this selects all text nodes that are children of `p` elements that are children of the current node.

**Or, if you want to exclude white-space-only text-nodes, use**:

```
p/text()[normalize-space()]
```

**If you only want to select the n-th such text node use**:

```
p/text()[normalize-space()][1]
p/text()[normalize-space()][2]
```

.   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .

up to

```
p/text()[normalize-space()][$k]
```

where `$k` is the total number of such nodes:

```
count(p/text()[normalize-space()])
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be extracted with text().

for ex, the below xpath gives u the required result

//p/text()

Comment: I wouldn't be able to separate the data and identify it as data1,2,3 or 4

Comment: just a little addition to your answer,  '//p[position() == 0]/text()' adding position to filter out specific p markup.

Comment: @Furqan, that's just not correct. XPath is a 1-based language, and second, comparison operator should be `=`.

Comment: @Moak, how do you want to "identify" data2?